# How do I bind this src to an iFrame in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, youtube-api

How should I bind to an iframe src with something received back via the YouTube data api?

Can I set a string inside :src and concatenate onto the end of it?

```
/embed/'this.param.videoId'
```

The response returns an Id {{ video.snippet.resourceId.videoId }}, but the url contains other parts src=“https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx”

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide any code example?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @ ljubadr

Comment: Currently the iframe I'd like to bind to is hard coded because everything I've tried is returning an error:

    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ni9ab27l3Fo/"></iframe>

Comment: Would be great to do something like this:
<iframe :src=' "https://youtube.com/embed/" + "video.snippet.resourceId.videoId" '></iframe>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
 :src="ytEmbedUrl + video.snippet.resourceId.videoId"
```

Answer (score 1):

iframe resolving only when there's a videoId:

```
<iframe v-if="videoId" :src="mySrc"></iframe>
```

computed property:

```
computed: {
  mySrc: {
    get: function() {
      //concat using template literal
      return `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.videoId}`
    }
  }
}
```

data property:

```
{
  videoId: false
}
```

Your method to assign to it:

```
methods: {
  getMyVideo() {
    video = // get my video code
    this.videoId = video.snippet.resourceId.videoId
  }
}
```

Or just inline it if you're super lazy:

```
<iframe src="`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is working great so far, but when I use back ticks within vue I get an infinite loop inside the console saying that I can't find my logo?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is working for me with Bootstrap V5 css

```
<template>
  <section class="video-player-container">
    <div class="video-player-row">
      <div
        class="video-player ratio"
        :class="`ratio-${group.videoAspectRatio}`"
      >
        <iframe
          loading="lazy"
          :src="`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${getIdFromURL(group.videoEmbedLink)}?rel=0`"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VideoPlayer',
  props: {
    group: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getIdFromURL (url) {
      const youtubeRegexp = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig
      let id = url.replace(youtubeRegexp, '$1')

      if (id.includes(';')) {
        const pieces = id.split(';')

        if (pieces[1].includes('%')) {
          const uriComponent = decodeURIComponent(pieces[1])
          id = `http://youtube.com${uriComponent}`.replace(youtubeRegexp, '$1')
        } else {
          id = pieces[0]
        }
      } else if (id.includes('#')) {
        id = id.split('#')[0]
      }

      return id
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .video-player {
    &-container {
      @include make-container();
      @include default-max-widths();
    }

    &-row {
      @include make-row();
    }
  }
</style>
```